# Information on Tavori and Dreizin ranged hash function?

Tags: hash

While doing some digging around in the GNU implementation of the C++ standard library I came across a section in `bits/hashtabe.h` that refers to a hash function "in the terminology of Tavori and Dreizin" (see below). I have tried without success to find information on these people, in the hopes of learning about their hash function -- everything points to online versions of the file that the following extract is from. Can anyone give me some information on this?

```
*  @tparam _H1  The hash function. A unary function object with
*  argument type _Key and result type size_t. Return values should
*  be distributed over the entire range [0, numeric_limits<size_t>:::max()].
*
*  @tparam _H2  The range-hashing function (in the terminology of
*  Tavori and Dreizin).  A binary function object whose argument
*  types and result type are all size_t.  Given arguments r and N,
*  the return value is in the range [0, N).
*
*  @tparam _Hash  The ranged hash function (Tavori and Dreizin). A
*  binary function whose argument types are _Key and size_t and
*  whose result type is size_t.  Given arguments k and N, the
*  return value is in the range [0, N).  Default: hash(k, N) =
*  h2(h1(k), N).  If _Hash is anything other than the default, _H1
*  and _H2 are ignored.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read that passage as saying that Tavori and Dreizin introduced the terminology/concept of a "range-hashing function".  Presumably, that's a name they use for a hash function with some special properties.  In other words, I read that as implying not that Tavori and Dreizen introduced a specific hash function, but that they talk about a category of hash functions and gave it a name.

I don't know if that is what the authors actually meant; that's just how i would interpret it.

I tried searching on Google Scholar for these names and found nothing that seemed relevant.  A quick search turns up a reference to Ami Tavori at IBM (a past student of Prof. Meir Feder, working on computer science), but I don't know if that's who this is referring to.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Ami Tavory, Vladimir Dreizin (IBM), and Benjamin Kosnik (Red Hat) authored the "Policy-Based Data Structures" library. Ideas developed there were later used in the GNU implementation of the C++ standard library.

Link-only answers are typically discouraged, but let me post the link here anyway because it is not discoverable with Google in a simple way:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/

In particular, range hashing approach is described here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/hash_based_containers.html